# Efficient serialization of numpy boolean arrays

Tags: python, serialization, dictionary, numpy

I have hundreds of thousands of NumPy boolean arrays that I would like to use as keys to a dictionary. (The values of this dictionary are the number of times we've observed each of these arrays.) Since NumPy arrays are not hashable and can't be used as keys themselves. I would like to serialize these arrays as efficiently as possible.

We have two definitions for efficiency to address, here:

1. Efficiency in memory usage; smaller is better
2. Efficiency in computational time serializing and reconstituting the array; less time is better

I'm looking to strike a good balance between these two competing interests, however, efficient memory usage is more important to me and I'm willing to sacrifice computing time.

There are two properties that I hope will make this task easier:

1. I can guarantee that all arrays have the same size and shape
2. The arrays are boolean, which means that it is possible to simply represent them as a sequence of `1`s and `0`s, a bit sequence

Is there an efficient Python (2.7, or, if possible, 2.6) data structure that I could serialize these to (perhaps some sort of bytes structure), and could you provide an example of the conversion between an array and this structure, and from the structure back to the original array?

Note that it is not necessary to store information about whether each index was `True` or `False`; a structure that simply stored indices where the array was `True` would be sufficient to reconstitute the array.

A sufficient solution would work for a 1-dimensional array, but a good solution would also work for a 2-dimensional array, and a *great* solution would work for arrays of even higher dimensions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initially, I suggested using [`bitarray`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray). However, as rightly pointed out by @senderle, since `bitarray` is mutable, it can't be used to directly key into a `dict`.

Here is a revised solution (still based on `bitarray` internally):

```
import bitarray

class BoolArray(object):

  # create from an ndarray
  def __init__(self, array):
    ba = bitarray.bitarray()
    ba.pack(array.tostring())
    self.arr = ba.tostring()
    self.shape = array.shape
    self.size = array.size

  # convert back to an ndarray
  def to_array(self):
    ba = bitarray.bitarray()
    ba.fromstring(self.arr)
    ret = np.fromstring(ba.unpack(), dtype=np.bool)[:self.size]
    return ret.reshape(self.shape)

  def __cmp__(self, other):
    return cmp(self.arr, other.arr)

  def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.arr)

import numpy as np

x = (np.random.random((2,3,2))>0.5)
b1 = BoolArray(x)
b2 = BoolArray(x)
d = {b1: 12}
d[b2] += 1
print d
print b1.to_array()
```

This works with Python 2.5+, requires one bit per array element and supports arrays of any shape/dimensions.

EDIT: In the recent versions, you have to replace the `ba.tostring` and `ba.fromstring` to `ba.tobytes` and `ba.frombytes` (Deprecated since version 0.4.0).

Comment: Aren't bitarrays mutable though? You can use them as dict keys but their hashes aren't content-dependent. So if you alter `b`, its hash doesn't change, and if you create `c` with the same contents, its hash differs from `b`'s hash. That seems problematic to me... still, +1 for `tostring`, which I stole :).

Comment: @senderle The fact that if you change `b` its hash does not change is not a concern, because we would never change `b` once instantiated. The fact that a `c` with identical contents to `b` will have a different hash than `b` is a **significant** problem though.

Comment: @gotgenes: I think you may be commenting on an old version of my answer. It's been rewritten since.

Comment: @senderle My comment above is indeed for an earlier edit of your answer; the current answer does not suffer from the hashing issue. Very nice!

Comment: This is a good compromise. Using `a = (random(210*210) > 0.5).reshape(210, 210)`, `%timeit BoolArray(a).to_array()` takes 1.45 ms per loop, which is ~60X slower than `%timeit numpy.fromstring(a.tostring(), dtype=bool).reshape(210, 210)`, but if you can trust `sys.getsizeof`, then `sys.getsizeof(BoolArray(a))` gives 28 bytes, but `sys.getsizeof(a.tostring())` gives 44121 bytes, so it consumes > 1500X less memory.

Comment: @gotgenes, see my edit, which I guess I was working on while these comments were posted. I don't think you can trust `sys.getsizeof`; it doesn't report the size of attributes, only the size of the object and its pointers. Try `sys.getsizeof(['a' * 1000000])` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 13):

I have three suggestions. My first is baldly stolen from [aix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694835/efficient-serialization-of-numpy-boolean-arrays/6695272#6695272). The problem is that `bitarray` objects are mutable, and their `hash`es are content-independent (i.e. for bitarray `b`, `hash(b) == id(b)`). This can be worked around, as aix's answer shows, but in fact you don't need `bitarray`s at all -- you can just use `tostring`!

```
In [1]: import numpy
In [2]: a = numpy.arange(25).reshape((5, 5))
In [3]: (a > 10).tostring()
Out[3]: '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01
         \x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01'
```

Now we have an immutable string of bytes, perfectly suitable for use as a dictionary key. To be clear, note that those escapes aren't escaped, so this is as compact as you can get without `bitstring`-style serialization.

```
In [4]: len((a > 10).tostring())
Out[4]: 25
```

Converting back is easy and fast:

```
In [5]: numpy.fromstring((a > 10).tostring(), dtype=bool).reshape(5, 5)
Out[5]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
In [6]: %timeit numpy.fromstring((a > 10).tostring(), dtype=bool).reshape(5, 5)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.75 us per loop
```

Like aix, I was unable to figure out how to store dimension information in a simple way. If you must have that, then you may have to put up with longer keys. `cPickle` seems like a good choice though. Still, its output is 10x as big...

```
In [7]: import cPickle
In [8]: len(cPickle.dumps(a > 10))
Out[8]: 255
```

It's also slower:

```
In [9]: cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps(a > 10))
Out[9]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
In [10]: %timeit cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps(a > 10))
10000 loops, best of 3: 45.8 us per loop
```

My third suggestion uses [`bitstring`](http://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/)s -- specifically, `bitstring.ConstBitArray`. It's similar in spirit to `aix`'s solution, but `ConstBitArray`s are immutable, so they do what you want, `hash`-wise.

```
In [11]: import bitstring
```

You have to flatten the numpy array explicitly:

```
In [12]: b = bitstring.ConstBitArray((a > 10).flat)
In [13]: b.bin
Out[13]: '0b0000000000011111111111111'
```

It's immutable so it hashes well:

```
In [14]: hash(b)
Out[14]: 12144
```

It's super-easy to convert back into an array, but again, shape information is lost.

```
In [15]: numpy.array(b).reshape(5, 5)
Out[15]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

It's also the slowest option by far:

```
In [16]: %timeit numpy.array(b).reshape(5, 5)
1000 loops, best of 3: 240 us per loop
```

---

Here's some more information. I kept fiddling around and testing things and came up with the following. First, `bitarray` is **way** faster than `bitstring` when you use it right:

```
In [1]: %timeit numpy.array(bitstring.ConstBitArray(a.flat)).reshape(5, 5)
1000 loops, best of 3: 283 us per loop

In [2]: %timeit numpy.array(bitarray.bitarray(a.flat)).reshape(5, 5)
10000 loops, best of 3: 19.9 us per loop
```

Second, as you can see from the above, all the `tostring` shenanigans are unnecessary; you could also just explicitly flatten the `numpy` array. But actually, aix's method is faster, so that's what the now-revised numbers below are based on.

So here's a full rundown of the results. First, definitions:

```
small_nda = numpy.arange(25).reshape(5, 5) > 10
big_nda = numpy.arange(10000).reshape(100, 100) > 5000
small_barray = bitarray.bitarray(small_nda.flat)
big_barray = bitarray.bitarray(big_nda.flat)
small_bstr = bitstring.ConstBitArray(small_nda.flat)
big_bstr = bitstring.ConstBitArray(big_nda.flat)
```

`keysize` is the result of `sys.getsizeof({small|big}_nda.tostring())`, `sys.getsizeof({small|big}_barray) + sys.getsizeof({small|big}_barray.tostring())`, or `sys.getsizeof({small|big}_bstr) + sys.getsizeof({small|big}_bstr.tobytes())` -- both the latter methods return bitstrings packed into bytes, so they should be good estimates of the space taken by each.

`speed` is the time it takes to convert from `{small|big}_nda` to a key and back, plus the time it takes to convert a `bitarray` object into a string for hashing, which is either a one-time cost if you cache the string or a cost per dict operation if you don't cache it.

```
         small_nda   big_nda   small_barray   big_barray   small_bstr   big_bstr

keysize  64          10040     148            1394         100          1346

speed    2.05 us     3.15 us   3.81 us        96.3 us      277 us       92.2ms  
                             + 161 ns       + 257 ns
```

As you can see, `bitarray` is impressively fast, and aix's suggestion of a subclass of `bitarray` should work well. Certainly it's a lot faster than `bitstring`. Glad to see that you accepted that answer.

On the other hand, I still feel attached to the `numpy.array.tostring()` method. The keys it generates are, asymptotically, 8x as large, but the speedup you get for big arrays remains substantial -- about 30x on my machine for large arrays. It's a good tradeoff. Still, it's probably not enough to bother with until it becomes the bottleneck.

Comment: @gotgenes, Actually, thinking about it more, it wouldn't be so hard to create a key containing both data and shape information. Just do `key = (bitstring.ConstBitArray(a.flat), a.shape)` or `key = (a.tostring(), a.shape)`.

Comment: We will know the shape of the arrays ahead of time (since they are uniform, this is stored elsewhere in the program), so it is no problem if that information is not included in the serialization. A sufficient solution is one which serializes the content and, given the dimensions externally, can reconstitute the original array. Someone else may find storing the shape very useful, though (for example, if they have arrays of different sizes), so it's nice that you're thinking of that case.

Comment: The timings are superb; thank you for adding those. I believe the timing for the `bitstring` example should be `%timeit numpy.array(bitstring.ConstBitArray((a > 10).flat)).reshape(5, 5)`, to match with the serialization and reconstitution pattern of the other timings. Also to be even more fair to the timings, it would probably be better if `a` were already boolean, e.g., `a = a > 10`.

Comment: You went above and beyond with the follow up timings and memory measurements! Superb! I wish I could give you more upvotes myself!

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the array to an bitfield using np.packbits. This is fairly memory efficient, it uses all the bits of a byte. Still the code is relatively simple.

```
import numpy as np
array=np.array([True,False]*20)
Hash=np.packbits(array).tostring()
dict={}
dict[Hash]=10
print(np.unpackbits(np.fromstring(Hash,np.uint8)).astype(np.bool)[:len((array)])
```

Be careful with variable length bool arrays the code does not distinguish between an all False array of for example 6 or 7 members. For moredimensional arrays you will need some reshaping..

If this is still not efficient enough, and your arrays are large, you might be able to reduce the memory further by packing:

```
import bz2
Hash_compressed=bz2.compress(Hash,1)
```

It does not work for random, uncompressible data though