# Implement custom keys for dictionary so that 2 instances of same class match

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, hash

I have 2 instances of classes that I would like to resolve to the same key in a dictionary:

```
class CustomClass(): 
    def __hash__(self):
        return 2

a = CustomClass()        
b = CustomClass()        

dicty = {a : 1}
```

Here, a and b are not equal as being keys:

```
>>> a in dicty
True
>>> b in dicty
False
```

What exactly is happening with hash; it seemed like a second instance of the CustomClass should match the hashing? What is going on that these hashes do not match?

I just now discovered the actual class is what is being hashed. So how to add a custom dictionary key for a class (i.e. when I try to use a class as a key for a dictionary, how should it be stored so that a and b match)?

Note that in this case I do not care about keeping a link to the original object in the dictionary, I can work with some unusable key object; just it matters they resolve to the same.

EDIT:

Perhaps some advice on the actual case I'd like to solve is required.

I have classes containing boolean `np.arrays` of shape `(8,6)`. I want to hash these such that whenever this object is put into a dictionary, the comparison takes place on these values. I made a bitarray out of them according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694835/efficient-serialization-of-numpy-boolean-arrays) answer. I noticed it has a `__cmp__` there (thanks `thefourtheye` for showing I have to look there). However, my class can be updated, so I'd only like to hash the np.array when I'm actually trying to put it into a dictionary, and not on initiation (and thus storing the hashable bitarray whenever I **init**, since the np.array might be updated, such that the hash is not a real representation anymore). I know that whenever I would update the np.array, I could also update the hashed value, but I'd prefer to only hash once!

Comment: `so I'd only like to hash the np.array when I'm actually trying to put it into a dictionary` - Okay, lets say you stored in the dict. But if it can change latter, how will you get it from the dict?

Comment: I would not want to get it from the dict.

Comment: Then why bother storing it in the dict in the first place? Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: First, I populate a set with the initial hashed class objects. Afterwards, I dynamically generate a lot of redundant class objects, which I would like to count using a new dictionary, where whenever there is a hash hit, the count would be incremented. In the case of the counts, I do not care about whether the classes are completely equal, I just care about the hash value at that stage.

Comment: perhaps I should not try to `myset.add(myclassobject)` and test `myclassobject in mydict` but I should just do `myset.add(hash(myclassobject)` and `hash(myclassobject) in mydict` to only have to do the computations twice (compared to more if I would also hash in `__eq__` or `__cmp__`)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You broke the contract between `__hash__`, `__cmp__` and `__eq__`. Quoting the [`__hash__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__),

> **If a class does not define a `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` method it should not define a `__hash__()` operation either**; if it defines `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` but not `__hash__()`, its instances will not be usable in hashed collections. If a class defines mutable objects and implements a `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` method, it should not implement `__hash__()`, since hashable collection implementations require that a object’s hash value is immutable (if the object’s hash value changes, it will be in the wrong hash bucket).
>
> **User-defined classes have `__cmp__()` and `__hash__()` methods by default; with them, all objects compare unequal (except with themselves)** and `x.__hash__()` returns an appropriate value such that `x == y` implies both that `x is y` and `hash(x) == hash(y)`.

In your case, the hash value is the same for two objects and [hash Collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) is common in any hash implementation. So, Python compares the object being looked up with the help `__eq__` method and finds out that the actual object being searched is not the same as the object already stored in. That is why `b in dicty` returns `False`.

So, to fix your problem, define custom `__eq__` function also, like this

```
class CustomClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = <something>

    def __hash__(self):
        # Find hash value based on the `data`
        return hash(self.data)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.data == other.data
```

**Note:** `__hash__` value should always be the same for a given object. So, please make sure that the `data` is never changed after assigned initially. Otherwise you ll never be able to get the object from the dictionary, since `hash` value of `data` will be different, if it changes in the later point of time.

Comment: Might I assume that np.array(dtype=bool) of shape (8,6) in its 262144 possible states would never resolve to the same hash, and thus __ eq __ could always return False not to have an extra calculation needed?

Comment: My `__eq__` should basically be `hash(data) == hash(other.data)`, except that I would find it a waste to redo that test if it is not required?

Comment: With respect to your Note: whenever my object's data is changed, it became a different object in my application (and does not have to match)

Comment: @PascalvKooten Hmmm, its not very clear what you are trying to do. I get a feeling that you are focusing only on getting the Object in the dictionary but not worried about retrieving it back.

Answer (score 1):

`__hash__` just determines which bucket the value will be placed into. Within the bucket python always calls to `__eq__` to make sure it doesn't return an element that just happened to have the same hash, but which is in fact different, so you need to implement your own `__eq__` as well.

```py
class CustomClass():
    def __hash__(self):
        return 2

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return hash(other) == hash(self)


a = CustomClass()     
b = CustomClass()     

dicty = {a : 1}

print a in dicty
print b in dicty
print "a" in dicty
```

Comment: Does that mean that if my hash value is going to be different, I can just put `return True`? My actual `__hash__` requires a calculation and I do not want to have to do it also at the `__eq__` stage. Actually, this might set me up that suddenly all instances of classes would match?

Comment: I added an example code. Just putting `return True` is not enough, because then it will be equal to instances of other types as well, which I assume you don't want to happen.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now what you want. See my updated code. Just make your `__eq__` function compare hashes, this way elements with hash collisions will be actually considered equal in the dictionary

Comment: @PascalvKooten Hashable objects must be immutable, thus you only need ever have to calculate the hash value once. You can then cache the hash value in an attribute like `_hash` for future use.

Comment: @Ishamael However, this requires extra `hash` computations which I'm trying to avoid. What about always returning False? My main bet is that the hash values should never match if there are 262144 possible states

Comment: I just tested hashing all the values and indeed they never match (all the hashes are unique in value). Does that allow some kind of a shortcut not to have to `hash(other)` == `hash(self)` ?

Comment: hash is very unlikely to match, but it can. what you might want to do is to have your hash function do something along the lines of `if self.cachedHash is None: compute hash and store in self.cachedHash; else return self.cachedHash`

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `__eq__` method to make your object `hashable`.
The definition of `hashable` from doc:

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during 
>   its lifetime (it needs a __hash__() method), and can be
>   compared to other objects (it needs an __eq__() method). Hashable
>   objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the hash function can cause collisions -- different objects can produce the same hash value. As a result the final check to see if an object is present in a dict is still done using an equality comparison (ie. `x == y`). The hash value is first used to find the relevant objects quickly.

If you want the behaviour you describe then you must also override `__eq__` as well.

eg.

```
class CustomClass: 
    def __hash__(self):
        return 2
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return type(self) is type(other) and type(self) is CustomClass
```